# Understand FlateDecode encoded PDF Stream

Tags: java, pdf

I encoded a flatdecoded Stream of a PDF in **IText**, unfortunately I have a clean text but can't exactely tell what it means... in **PDF 32000** there is no documentation about this topic... is there any other documentation about this matter?

***example***

```
q
0 0 1 rg
0 0 520 150 re
f
0 g
Q
q
BT
36 806 Td
ET
Q
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (this is the document you referred to as *PDF 32000*, isn't it?) documents all the contents of your example stream, especially have a look at chapters 8 **Graphics** and 9 **Text**:

```
q
```

8.4.2 *Graphics State Stack*: **The q operator shall push a copy of the entire graphics state onto the stack.**

```
0 0 1 rg
```

Table 74 *Colour Operators*: **rg - Same as RG but used for nonstroking operations.**

ibidem: **RG - Set the stroking colour space to DeviceRGB (or the DefaultRGB colour space; see 8.6.5.6, "Default Colour Spaces") and set the colour to use for stroking operations. Each operand shall be a number between 0.0 (minimum intensity) and 1.0 (maximum intensity).**

```
0 0 520 150 re
```

Table 59 *Path Construction Operators*: **re - Append a rectangle to the current path as a complete subpath, with lower-left corner (x, y) and dimensions widthand height in user space.**

```
f
```

Table 60 *Path-Painting Operators*: **f - Fill the path, using the nonzero winding number rule to determine the region to fill (see 8.5.3.3.2, "Nonzero Winding Number Rule"). Any subpaths that are open shall be implicitly closed before being filled.**

```
0 g
```

Table 74 *Colour Operators*: **g - Same as G but used for nonstroking operations**

ibidem: **G - Set the stroking colour space to DeviceGray (or the DefaultGray colour space; see 8.6.5.6, "Default Colour Spaces") and set the gray level to use for stroking operations. gray shall be a number between 0.0 (black) and 1.0 (white).**

```
Q
q
```

8.4.2 *Graphics State Stack*: **The q operator shall push a copy of the entire graphics state onto the stack. The Q operator shall restore the entire graphics state to its former value by popping it from the stack.**

```
BT
```

9.4.1 *General* (in 9.4 *Text Objects*): **A text object begins with the BT operator and ends with the ET operator**

```
36 806 Td
```

Table 108 *Text-positioning operators*: **Td - Move to the start of the next line, offset from the start of the current line by (tx, ty). tx and ty shall denote numbers expressed in unscaled text space units. More precisely, this operator shall perform these assignments**

```
ET
```

9.4.1 *General* (in 9.4 *Text Objects*): **A text object begins with the BT operator and ends with the ET operator**

```
Q
```

8.4.2 *Graphics State Stack*: **The Q operator shall restore the entire graphics state to its former value by popping it from the stack.**

If you have questions concerning details of one or the other operations, you'll find lots of information in the surrounding clear text. If after studying that there still are questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4):

So basically this will:

1) Paint a filled 100% blue rectangle from the origin of the page (which is the lower left corner) and a width of 520 and height of 120 units (which equals roughly 7.2 x 1.6 inch)

2) None of the text commands do anything. The "Td" operator changes the text matrix but since there is no text drawn on the page you won't see anything. And because it's embedded in the "q .. Q" pair it also won't have any effect on anything following it on the page.